# Layout Design for android?

Tags: android, layout

I want to design app targeting two devices 10.1 inch tab and 4 inch mobile..How Should I write xml or activities ?  Should I create `4(Screen Sizes)*2(land-port)=8` layout folders?
or there is any other way to support all `screen sizes` and `orientation`?

Comment: You should have two layout xml files one for 4 inch Screen and other one for 10.1 inch, you shall place phone xml in layout folder and tab xml in layout-xlarge folder

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the official Android UI documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html.

Everything you asked is answered there, e.g. what´s the difference between dp, dip, density, etc.

Also, please refer to this question: [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)